Can the Casimir force produce a non-zero force component in the  y-direction when acting on plates arranged at an angle?
The Casimir force is typically considered between two parallel plates, where it results in an attractive force perpendicular to the plates. However, I came across an article in which the author suggests that if the plates are arranged at an angle to each other, there could be a non-zero force component in the y-direction. The author speculates that this directional force could potentially be harnessed for thrust or other applications.
I'm curious whether this claim holds up under scrutiny, or if there’s a way to disprove it.
Article:
https://vixra.org/pdf/1702.0328v1.pdf
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Использование-силы-Казимира-для-управляемого-(Ru)-Antipin/4c18c3a85a291bb75d95cae8483ef694c981fac4


To use this for thrust, you have to avoid an equal but opposite $y$-direction force from the exterior sides of the plates (the drawing only shows force on the internal side).
If you could neglect forces on the exterior sides, you would already have thrust by using only a single plate, but that is not allowed, also not in the ordinary Casimir effect with parallel plates, where the forces from both sides have to be considered. They almost cancel and only leave a small residue.
In this case, a similar complete calculation of the forces from all sides would be needed and the extra difficulty here is the sharp corner at the bottom. I did not take the time to look at what exactly the authors are doing to reach their claim.
But without that we can already say that:

To obey momentum conservation, the system would have to continuously emit downward radiation to obtain upward thrust (perhaps from the sharp point at the bottom?)
If it does indeed emit radiation it violates energy conservation, since it has no source of energy.

I leave it to you to study it further.
